# Nestjs Crud: Filter join request to return only data of current user

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Currently I got his in my Controller:

```
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Broker
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      user: {
        eager: true,
        exclude: ['password']
      }
    }
  }
})
@Controller('broker')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
export class BrokerController {
  constructor(public service: BrokerService) {}
}
```

There is a ***`one to many`*** relation between user and broker. I am authenticating the users by a jwt token and I need to filter the data on the id of the user. Is there any way to do this through the Crud configuration?

Comment: Is it that the `Broker` has many `users`? and do you need it over some special URL? As far as I know it provides custom querying methods. So if its on a specific route you can easily query using the current user's id

Comment: One User can have multiple Broker but one Broker belongs to one User - One to Many. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

As responded before by @ilker:

```
@CrudAuth({
  property: 'user',
  filter: (user) => ({
    userid: user.userid,
  })
})
```

This will get the "user" from the JWT token, and you can use it to filter the entities.

@nestsjx/crud is very great library.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for adding details to @ilker's answer, this will probably help understand the solution. I am a bit uncomfortable keeping two answers this similar, however. It might have been better to suggest an edit on their post, or else give them explicit credit for the code here (which you almost did with "as responded before").

Comment: it will get the user from request object but not from the jwt

Answer (score 1):

In my case Broker entity is plant, so in Plant controller I have the following in order to get current user related entities and to get associated automatically on creation:

```
@CrudAuth({
  property: 'user',
  filter: (user) => ({ owner: user.userId }),
  persist: (user) => ({ owner: user.userId }),
})
```

Enabling TypeORM debug i can see that while POST works perfectly, when retrieving data seems it adds a `.id` to the underlying query performed by crud library:

```
SELECT `Plant`.`createdAt` AS `Plant_createdAt`, `Plant`.`updatedAt` AS 
`Plant_updatedAt`, `Plant`.`id` AS `Plant_id`, `Plant`.`name` AS 
`Plant_name`, `Plant`.`location` AS `Plant_location`, `Plant`.`power` AS 
`Plant_power`, `Plant`.`ownerId` FROM `plant` `Plant` WHERE 
(`Plant`.`ownerId.id` = '5605c0f6-4817-4ae1-9364-e341140b5182')
                 ^
                 ^
```

The insert query has not appended that ".id".
**Why is doing that at select time??**

I also add those entities definition to give more clues about my case:

**Plant:**

```
@Entity()
export class Plant extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
    default: 0,
  })
  power: number;

  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.plants)
  owner: User;
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string; //id comes from external authentication platform

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;

  
  @OneToMany((type) => Plant, (plant) => plant.owner)
  plants: Plant[];
}
```

Comment: I have also the same behavior, I don't know why. Where is the problem.

Comment: After a bit of research I found that library is probably using the wrong method to build the references which only works in certain cases. The fact is that i replaced in the compiled library @nestjsx/crud-typeorm/lib/typeorm-crud.service.js line 210 -> prop.databaseNameWithoutPrefixes; and works like a charm.

This is a temporary workaround which needs to be fixed through a library fork or PR.

Comment: Hello Jordi. Thank u. Working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware that would add a user id to the req.params from your session.
This is a trick, but I don't see another solution so far

Comment: I saw that you already had the same answer in github issues page :)
Here is a link for a "hacky" solution for others: https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/229#issuecomment-526956631

Answer (score 0):

```
@CrudAuth({
  property: 'user',
  filter: (user) => ({
    userid: user.userid,
  })
})
```

Comment: Please improve the quality of your answer with a few explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query like that :

```
@CrudAuth({
  property: 'user',
  filter: (user: User) => {
    return {
      'Tep.userId': user.id,
    };
  },
  persist: (user: User) => ({
    user,
  }),
})
```

With :

```
class Tep extends EntityHelper {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.teps)
  @JoinTable()
  public user: User;
}
```